# PAW vs USPP: Pseudopotentials in commercial DFT codes

Tags: quantum-chemistry, electronic-configuration, density-functional-theory

What is the difference between USPP (ultra-soft pseudopotential) and PAW (projector augmented wave) in commercial DFT codes?

Comment: Are you asking the difference in the algorithms or in utility/use?

Comment: This question is somewhat ambiguous, do you want a comparison of USPPs and PAWs in general or specifically within the commercial codes ? The more details and the more pointed your question is, the better answer we can give !

Comment: Here is the answer for a very similar question to yours: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1986